# How to loop through JSON with SwiftyJSON?

Tags: ios, json, swift, swifty-json

I have a json that I could parse with SwiftyJSON :

```
if let title = json["items"][2]["title"].string {
     println("title : \(title)")
}
```

Works perfectly.

But I couldn't loop through it. I tried two methods, the first one is

```
// TUTO :
//If json is .Dictionary
for (key: String, subJson: JSON) in json {
    ...
}
// WHAT I DID :
for (key: "title", subJson: json["items"]) in json {
    ...
}
```

XCode didn't accept the for loop declaration.

The second method :

```
// TUTO :
if let appArray = json["feed"]["entry"].arrayValue {
     ...
}
// WHAT I DID :
if let tab = json["items"].arrayValue {
     ...
}
```

XCode didn't accept the if statement.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

If you want loop through `json["items"]` array, try:

```
for (key, subJson) in json["items"] {
    if let title = subJson["title"].string {
        println(title)
    }
}
```

As for the second method, `.arrayValue` returns *non* `Optional` array, you should use `.array` instead:

```
if let items = json["items"].array {
    for item in items {
        if let title = item["title"].string {
            println(title)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: when I try looping through my dictionary of [String: JSON] I get the error: '[String : JSON]?' does not have a member named 'Generator'

Comment: because it's optional

Comment: @rintaro I used your method and it works, but I'm just not sure if I'm being efficient or not.  If you had multiple `items` to capture (ex. title, author, comment) would you simply repeat ` if let <<newItem>> = item["<<newItem>>"].string {}` for each of them?

Comment: @Craig.Pearce Basically, yes. But if you mind "efficiency", IMO you should not use SwiftyJSON. see: [SwiftyJSON Performance Issues](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29252158/3804019)

Comment: @rintaro - Very interesting.  For my initial application, SwiftyJSON should be ok, but I will bookmark that SO conversation for future consideration.  Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

I Find it a bit strange explained myself, because actually using:

```
for (key: String, subJson: JSON) in json {
   //Do something you want
}
```

gives syntax errors (in Swift 2.0 atleast)

correct was:

```
for (key, subJson) in json {
//Do something you want
}
```

Where indeed key is a string and subJson is a JSON object.

However I like to do it a little bit different, here is an example:

```
//jsonResult from API request,JSON result from Alamofire
   if let jsonArray = jsonResult?.array
    {
        //it is an array, each array contains a dictionary
        for item in jsonArray
        {
            if let jsonDict = item.dictionary //jsonDict : [String : JSON]?
            {
                //loop through all objects in this jsonDictionary
                let postId = jsonDict!["postId"]!.intValue
                let text = jsonDict!["text"]!.stringValue
                //...etc. ...create post object..etc.
                if(post != nil)
                {
                    posts.append(post!)
                }
            }
        }
   }
```

Comment: The correct syntax is for (key, subJson):(String, JSON) in json

Answer (score 8):

In the for loop, the type of `key` can't be of the type `"title"`. Since `"title"` is a string, go for : `key:String`. And then Inside the Loop you can specifically use `"title"` when you need it. And also the type of`subJson` has to be `JSON`.

And Since a JSON file can be considered as a 2D array, the `json["items'].arrayValue` will return multiple objects. It is highly advisable to use : `if let title = json["items"][2].arrayValue`.

Have a look at : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html

Comment: Please tick that green label on the left if I helped. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Please check the [README](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON/blob/master/README.md)

```
//If json is .Dictionary
for (key: String, subJson: JSON) in json {
   //Do something you want
}

//If json is .Array
//The `index` is 0..<json.count's string value
for (index: String, subJson: JSON) in json {
    //Do something you want
}
```

Comment: He stated in the question that he checked the docs. Not very helpful imo. Sorry.

Comment: This helped me quite a bit. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can iterate through the json by:

```
for (_,subJson):(String, JSON) in json {

   var title = subJson["items"]["2"]["title"].stringValue

   print(title)

}
```

have a look at the documentation of SwiftyJSON.
https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON
go through the Loop section of the documentation

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please [edit] your answer - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/21982654)