# SwiftyJSON loop with swift 1.2

Tags: json, swift, loops, swifty-json

[image]

I followed instructions on SwiftJSON on how to loop through, why the syntax error?

I am using SwiftyJSON xcode6.3 branch.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to loop through JSON with SwiftyJSON?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28365939/how-to-loop-through-json-with-swiftyjson)

Answer (score 1):

`"features"` in your for-loop is not a type, use `key: String` instead.

So your code becomes:

```
for (key: String, subJson: JSON) in json {
```